# Using type-only imports/exports in an older CRA project - how do I update babel loaders?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, create-react-app, babel-loader, type-only-import-export

I want to use the [type-only import/export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html.) syntax in an existing project generated by an older version of CRA. I upgraded TypeScript to 3.9.3, but when I try to `yarn start`, I also upgraded babel via `yarn upgrade Babel`, but I get the following error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:12)
>   File was processed with these loaders:
>    * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
>   * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
>   You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
>   > import type { Type } from "./Source";

same thing happens when I try exporting a type like `export type { Type }`, but `export Type = _Type` works fine.

I suppose I don't have the right babel loaders, how do I get them? Or is it something else? I use react-scripts 3.2.0

Comment: Did you find the answer to your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: The babel typescript plugin seems to be broken. The latest version doesn't understand `import type` or `export type` at all. I'm out of options, because I need the styled components plugin.